# Using GraphicsMagick in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, line, draw, system.drawing, graphicsmagick

I'm looking for an alternative to using the System.Drawing in Unity3D, since apparently Unity doesn't support it. I'd like to simply draw some lines on a texture. But I want options such as line width and edge rounding, which are fairly complex. GraphicsMagick seemed perfect, plus it's free.

So here's the steps I've already taken:

1) I changed my playersettings to use api compatability level 2.0, not "subset".

2) I downloaded [GraphicsMagick .Net 2.0 x64 wrapper](https://graphicsmagick.codeplex.com/), extracted the dll.

3) Right clicked the dll in Windows Explorer, selected properties, and unblocked the dll.

4) Put the dll into my assets/plugins folder.

5) Took the System.Drawing dll out of the \Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0 folder, and put it into my assets/plugins folder.

6) added reference to both those dlls in my project References (Visual Studio 2015).

7) added "using GraphicsMagick" to my c# script.

It compiles just fine in Visual Studio 2015, with no errors. But when I switch back to Unity, it says:

```
Assets/_GeoSphere/_ScriptsCS/DrawLineUV.cs(5,7): error CS0246: 
The type or namespace name `GraphicsMagick' could not be found.
Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

also, unity seems to remove the reference to GraphicsMagick from my project references.

So after heavy research into the issue, I am beginning to think the issue has something to do with the fact that the dll is unmanaged / native. I'm using Unity 5 free, but it is my understanding that it now supports native dlls.

I just want to draw a smooth, wide, and rounded-edged line! And I wouldn't mind the Bezier curves. If someone knows how to get GraphicsMagick to work in Unity3D, even if the process is rather involved, please elaborate. Thanks. :)

Comment: Update: I spoke to the developer of GraphicsMagick.net, and he is working to seperate the managed code from the unmanaged code, and put it into two seperate dll's, which would allow it to work in Unity. So for now I guess I wait till he is finished.