# GraphicsMagick.NET missing CORE_RL_bzlib_.lib file, C++ linker error?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, linker, graphicsmagick, .lib

I'm a long time VB programmer, and pretty good with c#, but I'm dumb as a brick when it comes to c++. But nonetheless, I need to build the source code for [GraphicsMagick.NET](https://graphicsmagick.codeplex.com/), specifically for .net 2.0 if I can, to try to see if I can convert it to a fully managed dll, so that I can import it into Unity3D (who cares why I need to build it?).

Anyway, without posting the entire project here, I realize it might be hard for anyone here to know exactly what is causing my error. But perhaps someone can give an educated guess? Edit: you can download a zip of the full source from https://graphicsmagick.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest if you want to see all the code I'm working with that is giving me this error.

This project, I assume, is supposed to compile without errors right out of the box. But it doesn't. It has this line of code in the include.h file:

```
#        if defined(HasBZLIB)
#          pragma comment(lib, "CORE_RL_bzlib_.lib")
#        endif
```

and as a result of this evil line, I'm getting this evil error:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'CORE_RL_coders_.lib'
GraphicsMagick.NET.net20
C:\Users\A\Downloads\graphicsmagick-d\GraphicsMagick.NET.net20\LINK 1
```

Being the good VB programmer, I searched my project folder extensively, and that _.lib file doesn't exist. But in the process of searching online, I learned that c++ sometimes generates .lib files when you build a project. So perhaps this file was supposed to be built first, before it was linked, but for whatever reason it didn't get built first? You can see how clueless I am with c++.

Of course I commented out the line. But then it simply generates an error on the next line, which is another .lib file missing. I assume it will generate an error on every _.lib file in the entire include.h file, and there are a fair number of them.

Why is this project, which is supposed to build, missing so many .lib files? Can anyone give an educated guess why? am I probably missing some dependency that the author of this project forgot to mention in the installation instructions? Or would it be more likely that these .lib files are supposed to be created by me somehow, and I'm just not building it right?

Comment: Sounds to me like compiling fails because on of the dependencies ("bzlib" at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bzlib ?) failed to be found. I'll check back when I can compile it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the downloaded release under `GraphicsMagick` there are two script files called `CopyLibsFromDropbox.cmd` and `CopyLibsToDropbox.cmd`, the first of which contains

```
echo You can download the library files here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a8krszzmo76fqkt/AAAc9Jho29Jk3iLrKhsBmw-Ma?dl=0
goto done
```

In that dropbox, you will find all the lib files you need. Download the whole thing as a `.zip` and extract the thing inside the the `\GraphicsMagick` directory.  Should look like that now: 
[image]

Once the libs are inside that folder you can actually compile the code. The scripts are for copying them from your local dropbox directory to this directory, if you choose to "save this inside my dropbox" at the dropbox download page above. In the end, you should see something like

```
3>  GraphicsMagick.NET.Web -> C:\Users\Maxi\Downloads\graphicsmagick-d1b5b1b28f26cdedf3ceeb555b94a87609286740\GraphicsMagick.NET.Web\bin\ReleaseQ16\x86\GraphicsMagick.NET.Web-x86.dll
3>  Codeanalysis is beeing executed...
3>  Codeanalysis finished -- 0 Errors, 0 Warning(s)
========== Build: 2 successfull, 0 failed, 0 recent, 1 skipped ==========
```

> (who cares why I need to build it?)

I do. You can already include managed dlls to Unity, and GraphicsMagick.NET already gives you a .NET dll which you should be able to use within Unity, or did you have any particular problems with that? Need some image processing functionality from that library?

Comment: Wow thanks for this fast answer. This GraphicsMagick.net is an unmanaged / native dll, which Unity has issues with. See my earlier SO question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067289/using-graphicsmagick-in-unity3d